# Ontology for QoS, i.e. download/upload speed, throughput

Tags: standards, rdf, ontology, computing, semantic-web

There are lots of papers, but don't publish their actual ontology, only give you figures/graphs (i.e. QoSOnt, OWL-QoS).

Is there a properly hosted ontology with an actual owl file and namespace defined? like
https://www.w3.org/2005/Incubator/ssn/ssnx/ssn#Latency

But I still need download/upload speed, throughput.

I have searched on

https://lov.linkeddata.es/dataset/lov/terms

http://schema.org

Comment: Maybe give us a link to that paper?

Comment: Ok, I found https://repository.lboro.ac.uk/articles/conference_contribution/QoSOnt_an_ontology_for_QoS_in_service-centric_systems/9404912, that's from 2005 and the change that ontology is still alive is very low.